# How to make a Linux Scheduler Gantt Chart?

Tags: linux, operating-system, scheduling, gantt-chart

I am studying the linux process scheduler but I can not figure out how to make the Gantt chart for this situation:

```
Process | Arrival | Burst Time | Sched. Class | RT Priority | RT Quantum | Nice
  P1    |    0    |     19     |      TS      |      0      |            |  -5
  P2    |    7    |      5     |     RT-RR    |      2      |      5     |
  P3    |   11    |     14     |     RT-FCFS  |      4      |            |
  P4    |   13    |      4     |      TS      |      0      |            |  -5
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

For display this information from the table in Ganntt chart you can use just Excel. [That](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NrfOtqzz_wk) is the example of how do it with Excel 2010

Comment: Well, this video show how to create a Gantt Chart from the table using Excel but I need an explanation step by step on how to create this Chart on a paper sheet. I have some difficulty in understanding how to calculate credit for time sharing processes and I have not understood how it works the mechanism of ages (ie when all processes have completed the time-sharing credits, these are recalculated).